# Is there a way to randomize the position of an object in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to program my first game where a part of the game involves randomizing the position of a red block along the x axis while keeping its y coordinate a constant.

**What I actually want** is for the box to appear at random positions between (-400, 350) [the left-most position] to (400, 350) [the right-most position]

This is what I have done so far. The result is a box that blinks in the same place in the middle of the screen while another box stays solid in another position.

```
import sys
import random
import time
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor ("black")
wn.setup (width=800, height=600)

droid_pos = [random.randint (-401, 401),300]

for i in range(-401, 401):
    droid_box = turtle.Turtle()
    droid_box.speed (0)
    droid_box.shape ("square")
    droid_box.color ("red")
    droid_box.shapesize (stretch_wid = 1, stretch_len = 1)
    droid_box.penup()
    droid_box.goto(droid_pos)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `droid_pos` inside the for loop, if you put it outside it alway be constant. And you also need to put the `droid_box` initialize code outside for loop to make it only one object. Try this:

```
droid_box = turtle.Turtle()
droid_box.speed(0)
droid_box.shape("square")
droid_box.color("red")
droid_box.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
droid_box.penup()

for i in range(-401, 401):
    droid_pos = [random.randint(-401, 401), 0]
    droid_box.goto(droid_pos)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```